# Excluding 2 words from search - match /word/ but not /a word/

Tags: regex

I need to search my corpus for the word `game` but I would like to specify the search to exclude one of the uses of the word: `a game`. So actually I need to exclude the string a+space+game

I was trying to compose the regex search string, but unsuccessfully:
`\bgame\b^(?!.*?[a gam]).*`

I'm sorry if I'm asking a question that has already been answered before. The thing is I'm not sure what to look for to get the answer.

Comment: What tool/language are you implementing this regex in?

Comment: I'm using AntConc for this particular case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`game` that is not preceded by `a_`? You can use a negative lookbehind.

```
(?<!a\s)game
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/2PQi1B/2

A more accurate version of this as suggested by Wiktor Stribiżew (to explicitly match word boundaries for edge cases):

```
r'(?<!\ba\s)\bgame\b
```

Comment: @Wiktor, @COLDSPEED: Can you explain what the `r'` does?

Comment: @mickmackusa: That would match `degame`.

Comment: @Wiktor Thank you. Is that a regex definition or is it coming from another language?

Comment: Sorry for a sort of confusion: I suggested to use `(?<!\ba\s)\bgame\b` to match a whole word `game` if it is not preceded with an indefinite article `a` (also as a whole word). Also note that in case there are 2 whitespaces or more, this negative lookbehind approach won't work unless the engine supports indefinite width lookbehind (.NET, PyPi Python regex).

Comment: I have one more query - I need to exclude from my search instances such as "a *great* game". I was trying to specify the grep, but I guess I must be doing something wrong ...: (?<!a\s|?\w\s)\bgame\b If someone could help me out again, it would be really great! thanks

Comment: @Karolina Would love to help. Will you open a new question?